# Stripping the domain name from a url

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery

I'm working with Big Query's Hacker News dataset, and was looking at which urls have the most news stories. I'd also like to strip the domain names out, and see which of those have the most news stories. I'm  working in R, and am having a bit of trouble getting the follow query to work.

```
 sql_domain <- "SELECT url,
                       REPLACE(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, '//') 
                           THEN url ELSE 'http://' + url END, '&', '?') AS domain_name,
                       COUNT(domain_name) as story_number
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full`
                WHERE type = 'story'
                GROUP BY domain_name
                ORDER BY story_number DESC
                LIMIT 10"
```

I've been getting the following error: "Error: No matching signature for operator + for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: INT64 + INT64; FLOAT64 + FLOAT64; NUMERIC + NUMERIC"

Can't for the life of me figure out a replacement for the "+" operator. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you also need to strip top level domain? i.e. do you need `stackoverflow.com` or `stackoverflow`? If you need the latter, then you have stumbled upon a huge problem since everything can be a top level domain nowadays - Check `library(urltools)` in R for URL parsing.

Comment: @Sotos stackoverflow.com would be fine! I'll check out urltools though, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't for the life of me figure out a replacement for the "+" operator

In BigQuery - instead of `'http://' + url` you should use `CONCAT('http://', url)`

Comment: Thank you @MikhailBerlyant! Now to figure out the next error, haha

Comment: meantime you can accept answer if it actually answered your current question! feel free to post new question(s) and we will be glad to answer them too

Comment: please consider voting up the answer if it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

For your goals (top domains submitting to Hacker News):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT NET.REG_DOMAIN(url) domain, COUNT(*) c
  , ROUND(EXP(AVG(LOG(IF(score<=0,0.1,score)))),2) avg_score
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full`
WHERE type = 'story'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Note how much easier is to call `NET.REG_DOMAIN()` to get the domain.

[image]

Comment: I don't get it... is it like the same question asked twice by the same person within 2 hours?

Comment: they were not at the same time. this one was specific to concatenation - so I asked OP to follow up on his next errors with posting new question

Comment: the question was `Can't for the life of me figure out a replacement for the "+" operator. Your help is much appreciated!` - but I see now - it can be confusing as titles are quite similar

Comment: :o) i learned to not to treat title as question per se and rather usually locating actual question(s) inside the post ...

Comment: hehe... I also read the opening statement "I'm working with Big Query's Hacker News dataset, and was looking at which urls have the most news stories. I'd also like to strip the domain names out, and see which of those have the most news stories. I'm working in R, and am having a bit of trouble getting the follow query to work."....

Comment: you are right - reading from different angles produces different impression about what is actually being asked. I think this is good thing - i mean having more answers on the same post :o)